# Google Ad Manager : The VAST url always shows "aderror:1009 The VAST response document is empty"

Tags: google-ad-manager

I created an audio Ad Unit like this

[audio ad unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xakq6.png)

and I follow the steps to create the VAST url

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaWut.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvOdm.png)

[step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxiD1.png)

then I get the VAST url

[https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?iu=/22691391158/audio_12345&description_url=[url]&tfcd=0&npa=0&ad_type=audio_video&sz=1x1%7C400x300%7C640x480&gdfp_req=1&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&env=vp&impl=s&correlator=](https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?iu=/22691391158/audio_12345&description_url=%5Burl%5D&tfcd=0&npa=0&ad_type=audio_video&sz=1x1%7C400x300%7C640x480&gdfp_req=1&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&env=vp&impl=s&correlator=)

[VAST url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sZDg.png)

and I put the url to Video Suite Inspector, and It shows "Ad error: AdError 1009: The VAST response document is empty.".

https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/vastinspector

[video suite inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V8Xa.png)

no ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you created the line items and have not assigned that ad unit yet. so you're missing the line items setting in your ad manager.